# Multiple y-axis with nvd3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I need to do a chart with 3-5 y-axes like on this image:
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fx_files/9016/1/addaxis_screenshot.jpg

Is it possible to do with NVD3.js ? Or maybe you know another fully free chart libraries which can do multiple y-axis.

Thanks.

Comment: It gets a bits restrictive with NVD3, you can use plain d3 for this. Have a look at this [example](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/e34791a32a54e015f57d)

Comment: Yes i saw this example and already made working prototype with 5 y-axes based on this example. But nvd3 (or another chart library) has a lot of other completed things, such as lines showing/hiding or changing chart type without reloading of the page and a lot of other stuff.